# Loading All Messages when scrolling top insted of some and statrting from down right away

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code make scrollbar starting from bottom but the problem that is
start from top and then the code scroll it to bottom  i want that the
message start from bottom right away

```
 $("#messagesDiv").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "slow");
```

This code load more messages when scrolling top the problem that it make all messages to load when it working simultaneously with
the code above

```
  $('#messagesDiv').on('scroll', function () {

        if ($('#messagesDiv').scrollTop() < 20) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: Why don't you set the scrollTop on load?

Comment: when on load its not working at all